# "invalid operands to binary expression" when using Boost.Geometry?

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, boost-geometry

I get a long compiler error when I try boost geometry difference function, while the union and intersection that have same interface and probably related implementation work:

```
bg::unique_(OldPolygon, Node->Polygon, NodePolygon); // compiles
bg::intersection(OldPolygon, Node->Polygon, NodePolygon); // compiles
bg::difference(OldPolygon, Node->Polygon, NodePolygon); // dies
```

The first error is:

```
boost/range/size.hpp:32:13: error: invalid operands to
    binary expression ('
         boost::reverse_iterator<
             __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<
                 const GraphPoint *,
                 std::vector<
                     GraphPoint,
                     std::allocator<GraphPoint>
                 >
             >
         >' and 'int')
            BOOST_ASSERT( (boost::end(rng) - boost::begin(rng)) >= 0 &&
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It seems for some reason the iterator difference is returning reverse iterator instead of distance...

The types are declared as:

```
namespace bg = boost::geometry;

struct GraphPoint
{
    int x, y;
    GraphPoint(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) { }
    GraphPoint() : x(0), y(0) { }
    GraphPoint(const GraphPoint &other) : x(other.x), y(other.y) { }

    bool operator ==(const GraphPoint &other) const
    {
        return x == other.x && y == other.y;
    }
};

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(GraphPoint, int, bg::cs::cartesian, x, y)

typedef bg::model::polygon<GraphPoint> Polygon;
typedef Polygon::ring_type Ring;
typedef bg::model::multi_polygon<Polygon> MultiPolygon;

MultiPolygon OldPolygon;
struct Node
{
    Polygon Polygon;
}
MultiPolygon NodePolygon;
```

The full error is in [here](http://pastebin.com/63sYfCQf) incase anyone likes to dig.
How can I make this compile?

Answer (score 0):

I successfully compiled an example based on your example with:

- VS2005 SP1 (Vista x64)
- boost 1.48.0 (just downloaded)

I had to modify the **Node** structure, this is the resulting code:

```
#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp> 
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/ring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/geometries.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/multi/geometries/multi_polygon.hpp> // boost 1_48_0
//#include <boost/geometry/multi/geometries/multi_geometries.hpp> // if boost comes from SVN

namespace bg = boost::geometry;

struct GraphPoint
{
    int x, y;
    GraphPoint(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) { }
    GraphPoint() : x(0), y(0) { }
    GraphPoint(const GraphPoint &other) : x(other.x), y(other.y) { }

    bool operator ==(const GraphPoint &other) const
    {
        return x == other.x && y == other.y;
    }
};

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(GraphPoint, int, bg::cs::cartesian, x, y)

typedef bg::model::polygon<GraphPoint> Polygon;
typedef Polygon::ring_type Ring;
typedef bg::model::multi_polygon<Polygon> MultiPolygon;

MultiPolygon OldPolygon;
MultiPolygon NodePolygon;

struct Node
{
    Polygon p;
} node;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    bg::unique(OldPolygon); // only one parameter
    bg::intersection(OldPolygon, node.p, NodePolygon);
    bg::difference(OldPolygon, node.p, NodePolygon);

    return 0;
}
```

I get two warnings (`warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data`) but it compiles.